# its possible to add any value in interface Props for initialization in React Typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I need some help, I'm just learning typescript, I want to limit my finco's value, but I can't do it my way, Is this possible? like this

```
interface Props {
  finco?: string = 'TAF' | 'ACC'
}
```

Comment: just use `finco?: 'TAF' | 'ACC'`

Comment: you save my day, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
interface Props {
  finco?: 'TAF' | 'ACC'
}
```

If you just put `'TAF' | 'ACC'` as the type, Typescript will only accept one of those two values as value of a the `finco` field.
(well, and also `undefined`)

Comment: think you mean undefined

Comment: Yep, fixed the answer